# SharePoint 2019 Change the default URL

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019

Would like to know how to change the default URL that was set after configuring SharePoint 2019 on-premise, currently it has the name of the server as the URL.

Answer (score 0):

1. First Obtain a Domain Name.
2. Add the Domain Name in the DNS.
3. Add IIS Bindings.
4. Add a new URL in Central Admin -> System Settings -> Uner Farm Management -> Configure Alternate Access Mappings.

First Add a new URL in the Default Zone and then change the old URL to the new one otherwise [image]SharePoint will not let you delete the Default URL.